# Are there any public plans known for Microsoft's Office Fabric UI to become supported in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, office-ui-fabric

Client-side Blazor was recently pushed to Alpha-release status by Microsoft almost at the same time as they depreciated JavaScript support for their Office 365 UI - Fluent - and promoted support for ReactJS.

Client-side Blazor has the potential to permit nearly all executable code in the Web-Browser to be written in C# (and not JavaScript). It's early days with Blazor, but it would seem inconceivable, to me, that Microsoft would ship a new UI (Blazor) without a decent set of UI-Controls themed to their product-set.

I am asking if there is any public information that Blazor support for the Fluent UI will be added over the remaining Alpha-release time period for Blazor?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no official plans from Microsoft to release FluentUI for Blazor, at least that I've seen.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. And you are pretty close to the matter. Patience is a virtue, I’m told.

Comment: That's what they say :)